# What should our FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, seven-questions, faq-proposed

This one is straight from [the list](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).  What should our FAQ contain? Obviously the general items about how to ask/answer, be nice, etc. We need to decide what we need that will be unique to our site. This seems mostly to be a statement of general categories that are on- or off-topic, e.g.:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users.
>   If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as
>         they interface with your computer
>         a shopping or buying recommendation

So we need to make this list. And is there anything else *specific to our site* that we'll need to add?

---

The Great Outdoors is for those who enjoy outdoor activities.
If your question is about...

- Camping and Backwoodsmanship
- Hiking, Mountaineering, and Climbing
- Fishing and Hunting
- First aid *as it relates to other outdoor activities*
- Watersports, including sailing and small boats

and it is not about...

- Medicine except the first aid described above
- Larger boats and yachts

...then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

If you are unsure whether your question is on-topic, feel free to ask on [The Great Outdoors Meta](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com).

---

Please continue adding feedback on the list, topics we should add to either list, ways to merge or generalize the existing items (it's a bit long, though probably not too long yet), etc.

Answer (score 7):

It is *not* about...

- traveling to your outdoor excursion (we have a travel site for those questions)
- medicine or first aid, except as they relate to commonly occurring situations or injuries obtained during outdoor activities

Comment: Would you consider [this question about poison ivy treatment](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/19/46) as off-topic?

Comment: @Psy I'd consider it on-topic because it's caused by a plant frequently encountered by outdoor adventurers in a pretty significant geographic area.

Comment: I would add something about the [bicycles stackexchange site](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/). There's potential for overlap (bicycle camping and the like) and it would help prevent migrations afterwards.

Comment: For hiking, there's a [question on whether traveling to the trailhead is on topic](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-asking-about-shuttle-services-for-trail-heads-off-topic)

Answer (score 6):

I vote that canoeing, kayaking, and whitewater rafting are on topic and should be reflected in the FAQ.
Should we including sailing or other boating topics? I vote no but am not sure if my reasoning is solid; I consider activities that take place outside using primarily power produced by you (rather than using wind or motors for boats) to be the parameters for what's included in "The Great Outdoors," but I welcome debate on that.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sure if I agree with the "power produced by you" logic - I'd say such activities are on topic, at least until or if we have another SE site where they fit better. I'd say such questions are fine as long as they relate to the outdoors more than the technicalities of the craft.

Answer (score 5):

These proposals were merged into the [Great Outdoors proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3659/the-great-outdoors) and so I assume are on-topic:

- [Backwoodsmanship](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23161/backwoodsmanship)
- [Hiking](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3595/hiking)
- [Mountaineering and Climbing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13170/mountaineering-and-climbing-including-indoor-climbing)
- [Fishing and Hunting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/17899/fishing-and-hunting)

Comment: Climbing might be a tricky one here...the merged proposal specifically included indoor climbing as on-topic. Should we do the same even though it is, by definition, not part of the "great outdoors"? I say yes because techniques and equipment are similar, so many questions that could be asked about indoor climbing apply to outdoor climbing as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as differentiating from other stack exchange sites, I think it's important to note that we're not a general fitness exchange and that already exists. Otherwise I don't know that there is much overlap with existing stackexchange sites. Caloric burn while hiking is sort of a grey area that might be better handled on the fitness site, unless it's in the context of packing food for hikes, etc.

Comment: What about preparing/training for a hike, should that be considered on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

I think we should also add something clarifying that (well-phrased) beginner questions, i.e. questions on "getting started" with various aspects of the outdoors are ok (providing they fulfil other requirements of being good questions.)

It might seem obvious, but for various other SE sites it seems these sorts of questions are frowned upon (electronics springs to mind.) While we should definitely welcome and encourage "advanced" more specialised questions on the outdoors, I think this site does also lend itself well towards helping those not so familiar with the topic.

Answer (score 1):

I vote we add snowsports to the list. There are already a number of skiing- and snowboarding-related questions on the site. Perhaps this is already counted under 'mountaineering', but I think it could be a little more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Some variation on the **10 Essentials** would be good fodder for the FAQ. One question I've a couple of today had to do with **safety in cold weather**.

The FAQ could contain weather- or season-appropriate lists of gear and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The FAQ needs a general disclaimer about the risks of plant identification for consumption and a warning to always make certain about what you're eating before chowing down.

Comment: -1, this belongs in a generic site disclaimer, not in a FAQ.