# Would skydiving questions be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I see it as part of the great outdoors, but I'm not sure if it would benefit the general public community.

Answer (score 9):

I wouldn't see it as a problem, along with other things like Bungee Jumping, etc.

Comment: I  quite  agree..

Comment: Although Extreme Ironing may be out :) I don't see a problem with Skydiving questions..

Comment: [It needs a tag then. The original seems to have expired.](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/skydive-equipment)

Answer (score 2):

To play devil's advocate here, though, what qualifies skydiving as an outdoor activity (aside from the very obvious fact that it happens - though briefly - in the outdoors (air))

Yes its a slippery slope, but it seems skydiving particularly leans into the "[driving a semi through the wildlands](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-outdoors-include-sailing-climbing-kayaking-and-other-pursuits)" end of things, being that it is wholly dependent upon an airplane.

Though, para-sailing / hang-gliding might fit...

Comment: I guess you probably need quite a bit of training unless you are in tandem..