# Kayaking, here or sports?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question:  [How does one steer a two-person kayak?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/how-does-one-steer-a-two-person-kayak)

Had this comment:  (This question could also be asked on the [sports.stackexchange.com](http://sports.stackexchange.com) site)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't really matter whether it's on-topic on sports, questions can (and often are) on-topic on more than one site. All that really matters is whether it's on-topic here, and kayaking, along with a number of other watersports, [has been fairly clearly determined to be on-topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16/18).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kevin. However if anytime anyone wants to make a distinction it could be made on the grade of intensity something is being done. Neither sports nor great outdoors currently has a meaningful faq to distinguish such questions as the one asked about.

Although I originally made the comment, that this could be moved or copied to sports, it's probably a better fit here because it would apply to beginners, not to experienced paddlers, and such is more likely to be found here.